# Page Factory - how does it work

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I've tried to implement one of our app modules by using PageFactory (for iOS)

Most of the elements are located by name and others by classname

In general everything works (more or less) but the thing is that the appium server has tons of logs , it seems that each time I'm trying to use some page control , and all the declared controls within that page are being update (?) which cause to longer time execution.

In case and I'm trying to debug my test , it takes a lot of time to move step by step (the appium server works extra hours ...)

I do use "CacheLookup" whenever it possible ...

Where my mistake is, or it's just should be like that ?

Thanks

Comment: Documentation for Page Factory is here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**
Not enough info provided to say for sure. If you have a bunch of cucumber steps and each step is creating a new page instance then yes, you could create a class variable to communicate between cucumber steps

Class variables get thrown out at the end of each scenario so no cross scenario contamination.  However, if a single scenario leaves a page and comes back you would need to explicitly set the class page handle to nil/null so that it is reinitialized upon reentry to that page. You want to avoid stale element errors.

Comment: What you are describing looks like "lazy loading", which Page Factory already does for you.

Comment: @SiKing Lazy initialization. You still need the class variable for that to work.Site_prism implemented Lazy initialization in v2.5 too so yes.  I'll update my answer.